# Get only the first 6 elements from querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get only the first 6 elements from my Array.
I have try it with that .slice(0, 6) but it´s wont work.
Maybe someone have a idea.
My Array have arround 15 Nodes , so i need only the first 6 to display in my table.

```js
        let xmlContent = '';
        let tableBooks = document.getElementById('books');
        fetch('info2.xml').then((response)=> {
            response.text().then((xml)=>{
                xmlContent = xml;

                let parser = new DOMParser();
                let xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlContent, 'application/xml');
                
                let container = xmlDOM.querySelector("[ID='91961']");
                let books = container.querySelectorAll("SAISON");
                
             books.slice(0,5).forEach(bookXmlNode => {

                    let row = document.createElement('tr');

                    //Saison
                    let td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.innerText = bookXmlNode.children[0].innerHTML;
                    row.appendChild(td);

                    //  von-bis
                    td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.innerText = bookXmlNode.children[1].innerHTML +" - " + bookXmlNode.children[2].innerHTML;
                    row.appendChild(td);
                    

                    //preis
                    td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.innerText = bookXmlNode.children[3].children[2].innerHTML +" €";
                    row.appendChild(td);
                    
                    

                    tableBooks.children[0].appendChild(row);
                    
                });
                
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi, provide some example data please.

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll("div")].slice(0,5)` or `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div")).slice(0,5)`

Comment: So why are you not doing `books.slice(0,5).forEach` if you do not need them all to be displayed?

Comment: books.slice(0,5).forEach ...look an easy way,but it don´t work

Answer (score 6):

> I need to get only the first 6 elements from my Array.

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) doesn't return an array, it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

> I have try it with that .slice(0, 6) but it´s wont work.

That's because `NodeList` instances don't have that method.

You can apply the Array one to them:

```
const firstSix = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("selector"), 0, 6);
```

Alternatively, you can spread out the elements into an array and then use `slice` on it:

```
const firstSix = [...document.querySelectorAll("selector")].slice(0, 6);
```

or create the array via `Array.from` rather than spread:

```
const firstSix = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("selector")).slice(0, 6);
```

Comment: Or `Array.from(....)`.

Comment: @FelixKling - Now if only there were an `Array.from(arrayLike, number, number)` signature... :-)

Answer (score 2):

First solution is to just not render the elements to start if you do not need the other elements to be rendered.

```
books.slice(0,5).forEach(... your code ...)
```

If you want the eleements to be rendered, and you want to select the rows still, you can just use a CSS Selector [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select 6 table rows

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#books > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n+6)"))
```

```html
<table id="books">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the reason your code did not work is because a `querySelectorAll` returns an html collection, so you need to convert the it over to array.

```
const rows1 = [...document.querySelectorAll("tr")].slice(0,6);
// or
const rows2 =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).slice(0,6)
```

Comment: Sorry , i dont understand it what i have to do!

Comment: What do you not understand? The one solution is to change your selector. The other solutions are to make the NodeList an Array.

Comment: I refresh my code on the top, but it wont work.

Comment: HOW can you select rows BEFORE you create them? Just do `books.slice(0,5).forEach` like I said

Comment: I update the code on the top with books.slice(0,5).forEach, but i get with this no results. I get an Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: books.slice is not a function